# Logic issue in code block with objects of different classes referring to a list

Tags: java

I am trying to make the following coding block a bit more efficient.  I am passing a List in a method and looping through it.  The list either came from object A or from object B that are objects NOT of the same class.  I am messing with each element and then for the elements that came from the List that came from object A I need toDoSomething(); but for the elements that came from the List which came from obejct B I need toDoSomethingElse();  For each element of both Lists I apply the exact same Logic, that's why I am using the same method on them.

```
for(Object x : List){
//some random code

    if(cameFromListA())
        doSomething();

    else
        doSomethingElse();

    
}
```

My problem with this code block is that I already know prior to looping whether the List came from object A or from object B so it is not efficient to check for each element from which list it came from since I already know.  The stupid solution would be to just write the code block twice for each object even though the same logic applies to them.  The method that I am using is void.  I need to somehow "block" a part of the code based on which object the List came from.

Comment: Why not implement 'doSomething()' separately inside A and B, assuming that those two objects are of different classes, and then pass the list's source object in?

Comment: I am writing on an API.. I cannot mess with A and B.. The only solution would be to make new classes and extend them, which seems too much for a single method call.

Comment: A little more context to your question may make the answer more obvious.  Rather than creating extensions of A and B you may want to use a decorator.  But is the problem here just the efficiency of the loop?  If that is your only issue then you should ask yourself whether you have a real performance problem or if you are simply trying to optimize code that already works.  In other words, are you trying to solve a performance problem you don't really have?

Comment: Yes.. I generally try to make my code as optimally as possible. I just hoped that somebody with more experience than me would have a simple answer. It is more of a me trying to optimize thing than a real performamce issue.. The context is minecraft basically.. I am coding a plugin that messes with the enchantments of an item. If the item is an enchanted book, in order to add an enchantment I need to chnage the EnchantmentStorageMeta of the book, which is a child of ItemMeta, in any other case I directly change the ItemMeta of the item. The same logic applies to book and items until this point.

Comment: It's hard to know what would work without seeing more of the code but you may want to look at creating a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for EnchantmentStorageMeta or ItemMeta.  Your question just is not detailed enough to give you a better answer.